# Rails twitter-api get acces token without "sign-in" and store it in a different model than user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, twitter

I have a rails app and I want to use the twitter api with the account of a user (to make favs, tweets, etc ...).

Here is my problem, I want the user to be able to create several "Project" with one different twitter account by project.

That is why I want to get the `access_token` and the `access_token_secret` but store them in my Project model and not in my User model.

I don't understand how I can do that. All the stuffs I found explain every time the way to do it with `Omniauth` and a "sign up"/"Sign in" of the User.

I'm very new to this `Oauth / callback / API` stuff so I'm a bit lost.

Is there an easy way to just get the `access_token` and the `access_token_secret`  and store it where I want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with saving information i needed in the session.

```
  def ask_twitter_authorisation
    session[:info] = @project
    redirect_to "/auth/twitter"
  end
```

and then use it in my callback

```
  def twitter_callback
    session_hash = session[:info]
    @project = Project.find(session_hash["id"])
    @project.t_access_token = auth_hash.credentials.token
    @project.t_access_token_secret = auth_hash.credentials.secret
    @project.save
  end
```